# Running windows 10 ubuntu bash commands from java

Tags: java, linux, bash, swing, ubuntu

T'm using windows 10, apparently the only way for me to run UNIX commands is to download ubuntu bash for windows 10.

I'm writing a java application using swing, which will run a set of UNIX commands upon clicking on the button, but I was thinking is it possible to run this commands with ubuntu bash for windows 10 ?

Comment: I don't know anything about running `bash` on Windows, but I'd guess that you'll need to run `bash.exe` as a program, and pass in your commands as standard input.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to run Unix commands on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that

> the only way for me to run UNIX commands is to download ubuntu bash
> for windows 10

, but it's not correct.

A rough search with the keyword "run linux command in windows" leads us to various solutions, above all, two, as stated [here](https://www.google.es/search?q=run+linux+command+in+windows&oq=run+linux+command+in+windows&aqs=chrome..69i57.6866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

1. Run Bash Shell from Windows 10
2. Install Cygwin.

Actually, I have a third way: install git for Windows to enable Bash in Windows. As stated [here](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). This approach may be more limited to Cygwin, I haven't test it.

I have installed both Cygwin x64 and git without conflict, so you can just use them in `cmd` console. I think your question may change into "How can I run Bash command in Java in Windows if the Bash is enabled?"

Now, I don't know if you have been aware of how to run Bash commands from Java. If so, you are done here. If not, ask Google.

---

A little more search before asking here is **always** helpful. Google is smarter than we think, and most of the time, even smarter than most of us, may we admit it or not.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `bash` is on your path, you can run the following cmd command run a bash one:

```
bash -c "<your command>"
```

Just combine this with the normal java way of running a command:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(String.format("bash -c \"%s\"", <your command>));
```